# A limit of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I can across a very tricky question i couldnt find the right answer

[image]

when I tried to solve it, what i got was:

[image]

My problem is that i couldnt remove or explain why it is ' $-1$ due to the $-2/5$

but its pretty clear the answer is -1 because at infinity it doesnt even matter

would LOVE to get a straight answer

Comment: For any scalar $a\in (-1,1)$, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} a^n = 0$

Answer (score 1):

Both $(\frac 2  5)^{n}$ and $(-\frac 2  5)^{n}$ tend to $0$. So the limit is $\frac {15 -0} {0-15} =-1$.

Comment: yea but for even N's and odd N's the number changes, therefore doesn't it considered to be diverges ?

Comment: @Lostdawn The sign of $(-\frac  2 5)^{n}$ has no effect on the answer because this quantity tends to $0$. Note that $x^{n} \to 0$ whenever |x| <1$.